# slideDown/slideUp navigation displaying strangely in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, slidedown, slideup

http://cougar.thepixelshopdev.ca/
I have a simple sub-nav that slides up/down on hover of "solutions" using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li.page-item-6").mouseover(function(){
        $('#dropdown-contain').clearQueue().slideDown();
        $("#dropdown-contain").mouseover(function(){
            $('#dropdown-contain').stop().css('display', 'block');
        });
    });

    $("#dropdown-contain").mouseout(function(){
        $('#dropdown-contain').clearQueue().slideUp();
    });

});
```

It works fine in all other browsers, including IE8 & 7. In IE9, on the first hover, it starts sliding down a couple hundred pixels further down the page than it should, and when it's done sliding pops back up to where it should be. When you hover over it a second time and every time after, it continues to slide up/down a couple hundred pixels further down the page.

Is this a bug in IE9? Any observations or suggestions are greatly appreciated!